# opencv and python error " name 'kernel' is not defined"

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm following the given example script present at the  link (http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html)  to object detection with sequential images and trying to find out contours, before to finding contour I want to implement dilate function but again and again this error is coming.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('j.png',0)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.dilate(img,kernel,iterations = 1)
```

I am using same code but his code also terminated with the error   `name kernel is not defined`.

Comment: The code seems to run fine now (after edits). Do you still get an error? What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Error was due to numpy installation. I searched alot and got some clue related to numpy. I re-installed numpy and everything is working fine now.